# JqGrid not working on Firefox 3.6.3 (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS version which has Firefox 3.6.3 version installed. I have a JqGrid in my web application which I am accessing from Firefox on Ubuntu system. But I do not see the navbar icons. Also the jQuery tabs do not work. What might be the problem?

OS : Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
JqGrid : version 4.1.2
FireFox : Version 3.6.3
Tabs : jquery-ui-1.8.1

The grid is displayed but the navbar icons (Add / Edit / Delete / Search / Reload) do not show. When we click on the tab it does not change the tabs.

@Update:

I do not have a link :( sorry about that. But on debugging the javascript on FireFox it was found that the functions which we are calling on events are not getting resolved.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
$("#userList").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager1",{add:true,edit:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true,
                  beforeRefresh: function(){
                    $("#userList").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'xml'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]);
                  }},
                   {  recreateForm:true,
                      beforeShowForm:checkCookieExpireForUser
                   },{
                      recreateForm:true,
                      beforeShowForm:checkCookieExpireForUser
                   },{
                      recreateForm:true,
                      beforeShowForm:checkCookieExpireForUser
               });
                    function checkCookieExpireForUser(formid) {
                        var currentdate = new Date();
                        var currentTime = currentdate.getTime();
                        if(currentTime > cookiInfo[6]) {
                           window.location.href = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/index.jsp';
                        }
                    }
```

When this code is executed in Firefox it says that `checkCookieExpireForUser` is undefied.

Comment: Do you have a example URL maybe? I'm running Ubuntu with FF as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

Here is how I solved the problem. This might be useful to any one who is facing same problem.

```
In Firefox you need to add the function definition before the call. When I moved the definition before the call. JqGrid icons where displayed and it is working fine.
```